# how to use php DateTime() function in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. I have try to use the

```
$now = DateTime();
$timestamp = $now->getTimestamp();
```

But it shows error likes this.

```
 FatalErrorException in ProjectsController.php line 70:
 Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\DateTime()
```

What Can I do?

Comment: Sure you want to do `$now = new DateTime();`?

Comment: I have tried it in the controller. But it shows undefined function error.

Comment: Actually I need to store my timestamp as unix timestamp. And I don't want to migrate my db.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`DateTime` is not a function, but the [class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

When you just reference a class like `new DateTime()` PHP searches for the class in your **current namespace**. However the `DateTime` class obviously doesn't exists in your controllers namespace but rather in root namespace.

You can either reference it in the root namespace by prepending a backslash:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
```

Or add an import statement at the top:

```
use DateTime;

$now = new DateTime();
```

Answer (score 17):

Best way is to use the [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) dependency.

With `Carbon\Carbon::now();` you get the current Datetime.

With Carbon you can do like enything with the DateTime. Event things like this:

```
$tomorrow = Carbon::now()->addDay();
$lastWeek = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
```

Comment: This would be the most correct, Laravel way of doing it.

Comment: If I add `use DateTime;` in top of the page means works fine. Then what is the use of using Carbon?

Comment: of course, if you just need a DateTime and thats it, you got the perfect solution already.
But often you need to handle the DateTime in a view or something else. Here a example how powerful the Carbon is: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the current UNIX timestamp I'd just use [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

```
$timestamp = time();
```